# Makefile:7: target ( given more than once in the same rule

Tags: c++, makefile

im not familiar with make system. when i tried to execute the program like below, there is no problem:

```
./prog.out arg1 arg2 arg3
```

when i decided to it with make, i added the following script to makefile

```
parse ${parameters}:
     ./prog.out ${parameters}
```

its strange when the this works well;

```
 make parse parameters="aaa bbb ccc"
```

and these characters: '(' and ')' generates  errors!

```
make parse parameters="( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) )"
Makefile:7: target `(' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `d' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `,' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `(' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `d' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `,' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `d' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `)' given more than once in the same rule.
Makefile:7: target `)' given more than once in the same rule.
./prog.out  ( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) )
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [parse] Error 2
```

but this works well;

```
./prog.out "( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) )"
```

the make version is 3.81

any idea?

Comment: What were you trying to do by putting `${parameters}` in the `parse ${parameters}:` line?

Answer (score 3):

```
parse ${parameters}:
     ./prog.out ${parameters}
```

The above makefile snippet creates a target named `parse` and one for each word in the expansion of the variable `parameters`.

So in your invocation `make parse parameters="aaa bbb ccc"` the line expands to `parse aaa bbb ccc:` and you end up defining four targets `parse`, `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`.

With the invocation `make parse parameters="( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) )"` it expands to `parse ( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) ):` and you define the targets `parse,`d`,`(`,`,`and`)`with`d`being listed four times,`,`three times,`(`three times` and `)` three times. (Which is why make complains about the targets being redefined.

If you just want `parameters` used as a variable in the command that is run then you don't need it in the target line at all.

```
parse:
     ./prog.out "${parameters}"
```

and then use

```
make parse parameters="aaa bbb ccc
```

or

```
make parse parameters="( d , ( d , ( d , d ) ) )"
```

Answer (score 3):

Once I got the same issue, and after many headaches, I found that there were a few 'white spaces' after the definition of a variable (corresponding to a folder definition in my Makefile). Eliminating them make it works...

Answer (score 0):

On my side, the error mentioned by the OP was caused by having **a comment at the end of a variable declaration**.

```
MAIN := main.c # entry point
```

Moving the comment to another line (on its own), solved the issue.

```
# entry point
MAIN := main.c
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error.  The folder name had a space in it.  Eclipse does not handle spaces in folder names or project names well.

Comment: Not an answer, more of a comment. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer